# How to run phpUnit+selenium RC remote test cases to local browser

Tags: cakephp, selenium, phpunit

I am trying to run phpUnit+selenium RC remote test cases from local machine and get the output in our local browser web driver. I'd like to use a server on a remote machine and run the test on the server through ssh login and then get the output on our local browser.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to run remote test cases into local machine. Using following steps,

1. set the local ip in test case
2. run selenium RC in local machine
3. run the test case in server